# How to create a link for user to subscribe my Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I'm investigating a way to let users subscribe to my google calendar with a simple click on my web page, i.e., by a hyperlink.

As I know, users can subscribe to my calendar manually by;
"Add Subscribed Calendar" for Apple, and
"Add by URL" for Google.

Is there any way to trigger these action with a  link, or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well because I had several users that didn't know they had to click the little add button in the bottom right corner to actually subscribe.

After poking around I found a solution.

1. Open Google Calendar
2. In the top right corner click the cog wheel and select "Settings"
3. From the left sidebar select the Calendar you're wanting to create a subscribe link for
4. Scroll down to where it says "Access Permissions"
5. There is a button that says "Get Shareable Link" Click that

That URL created when launched in a tab for an account that isn't subscribed to that calendar will auto prompt the "subscribe to this calendar" functionality.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Google says that the request was sent, but no mail arrives at the owner. Does someone know what to do?

Comment: unsure what request or mail you're referring to.

tested on our local site and the links are infact opening a new tab and requesting the user to subscribe to the calendar we are linking to.

I wonder if it requires the user to be logged into the google in that browser already or if it would prompt a login.